# Laravel создать уникальные поля в таблице

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Есть таблица `book_authors` которая связывает две таблицы, `books` и `authors` связь многие-ко-многим. В таблицы `book_authors` есть поля `book_id` и `author_id`. Необходимо создать миграцию, чтобы обновить эти поля и сделать их уникальными, т.е. чтобы не было дубликатов записей, например не должно быть:

```
id  book_id  author_id
1      1          2
2      1          2
         ...
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте к вашей миграции вот этот код и база не позволит создать одинаковые значения

```
$table->dropColumn(['id']);
$table->primary(['book_id  ','author_id'], 'book_id_author_id_primary');
```

Comment: В итоге сделал так `$table->unique(['book_id','author_id'], 'book_id_author_id_unique');`. Не стал что-то удалять. Спасибо!